# I need to retrieve the value of dynamically created "DatePicker" on button Click

Tags: c#, xamarin

```
public int count = 1;
        Dictionary<DatePicker, int> StartDates = new Dictionary<DatePicker, int>();
        Dictionary<DatePicker, int> EndDates = new Dictionary<DatePicker, int>();

private void AddDateBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Grid grid1 = new Grid
            {
                ColumnDefinitions =
            {
                new ColumnDefinition{ Width = new GridLength(0.4, GridUnitType.Star)},
                new ColumnDefinition{ Width = new GridLength(0.6, GridUnitType.Star)}
            }
            };
            Label label1 = new Label
            {
                Text = "Start Date",
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Caption, typeof(Label)),
                TextColor = Color.Black
            };
            grid1.Children.Add(label1, 0, 0);
            DatePicker startdatePicker1 = new DatePicker
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Caption, typeof(Label)),
                TextColor = Color.Black
            };
            StartDates.Add(startdatePicker1, count);
            grid1.Children.Add(startdatePicker1, 1, 0);
            BoxView boxView = new BoxView
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                HeightRequest = 1,
                BackgroundColor = Color.LightGray

            };
            NewDurationStack.Children.Add(grid1);
            NewDurationStack.Children.Add(boxView);

            Grid grid2 = new Grid
            {
                ColumnDefinitions =
            {
                new ColumnDefinition{ Width = new GridLength(0.4, GridUnitType.Star)},
                new ColumnDefinition{ Width = new GridLength(0.6, GridUnitType.Star)}
            }
            };
            Label label2 = new Label
            {
                Text = "End Date",
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Caption, typeof(Label)),
                TextColor = Color.Black
            };
            grid2.Children.Add(label2, 0, 0);
            DatePicker enddatePicker1 = new DatePicker
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Caption, typeof(Label)),
                TextColor = Color.Black
            };
            grid2.Children.Add(enddatePicker1, 1, 0);
            EndDates.Add(enddatePicker1, count);

            BoxView boxView1 = new BoxView
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                HeightRequest = 1,
                BackgroundColor = Color.LightGray

            };
            NewDurationStack.Children.Add(grid2);
            NewDurationStack.Children.Add(boxView1);
        }
```

I have this Button click event which creates two DatePickers every time the user press that button. Users can create as many as they want. Also, this page includes a Request form users can have multiple requests. So on the same page user can create mutiple requests forms and every request can have multiple date ranges. so how can I get the values of all the dates at the end?
I try adding the controls to Dictionry but that works for one request form with multiple dates ranges not for multiple requests that have multiple date ranges.

Comment: Are you using XAML pages?

Comment: Yes only for one request form and its one date duration. Adding more using c# on button click.

Answer (score 0):

The method you use is a bit primitive. You can easily solve this using listview. [check this out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/)

first you add new element in `ObservableCollection<DatTime>` when button event is triggered. The `DatePicker` you specify only once in the `listview` will automatically replicate itself.

Comment: Can you please elaborate with the code!!

Answer (score 0):

You could get the date when you select the DatePicker with [DateSelected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/datepicker#datepicker-in-an-application) event,and then you could use KeyValue to store them.

For example in your codes above:

```
Dictionary<int, DateTime> startDateTimes = new Dictionary<int, DateTime>();
Dictionary<int, DateTime> endDateTimes = new Dictionary<int, DateTime>();

DatePicker startdatePicker1 = new DatePicker
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Caption, typeof(Label)),
            TextColor = Color.Black
        };
startdatePicker1.DateSelected += StartdatePicker1_DateSelected;
StartDates.Add(startdatePicker1, count);
...

 DatePicker enddatePicker1 = new DatePicker
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Caption, typeof(Label)),
            TextColor = Color.Black
        };
       enddatePicker1.DateSelected += EnddatePicker1_DateSelected;
       EndDates.Add(enddatePicker1, count);

private void StartdatePicker1_DateSelected(object sender, DateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DatePicker datePicker = sender as DatePicker;
        startDateTimes.Add(1, datePicker.Date); //1 corresponds to your count
    }

 private void EnddatePicker1_DateSelected(object sender, DateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DatePicker datePicker = sender as DatePicker;
        endDateTimes.Add(1, datePicker.Date); //1 corresponds to your count
    }
```